# How could I save users points on a fortune wheel?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a wheel of fortune on my website, and, when a user spins the wheel, and he earns points, his points are saved (with his IP address).

I found this fortune wheel http://jsbin.com/qefada/11/edit?html,js,output and I want to use it on my project.

The HTML code of the canvas for the fortune wheel:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

How could I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: How to do what?

Comment: Sounds like you need a login system and db to save the data (points) to users. Specially if you want them to comeback and continue playing the game. You will need server side code unless I'm not understanding what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AJAX POST request to send the value in `label[ai]` to a specific backend URL, that will save the value.

Example in Jquery: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.post( "/somepage.php", { name: "John", score: label[ai] } );
```